# how to calculate page rendering time with or without any javascript or with multiple javascript separately

Tags: javascript, jquery

how to calculate page rendering time with or without any javascript or with multiple JavaScript separately?

I want to know how much page will go slow if i use any javascript/jquery with plugin/ multiple javascript/jquery plugin files etc.?

javascript code in any form inline, in-page code, external file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good option is to use [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) (its "Net" panel) combined with [PageSpeed](http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/) (a Firebug plugin provided by Google) for testing your different configurations.

**Update:** Forgot to mention [YSlow](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/5369).